# Async loading of javascript files using MVC4 Bundling and HTML5 async attribute

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

HTML5 has an async attribute for script files, to enable async loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js" async></script>
```

I can take advantage of this with my MVC4 bundling by referencing the bundle like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/jquery")' async></script>
```

But what this does mean is my scripts are bundled even when in debug mode.

So how can I take advantage of bundling and the async attribute without loosing non-minification when in debug.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you upgrade to the 1.1-alpha1 release, you can just add the async attribute to the tag format either via:

```
Scripts.DefaultTagFormat = @"<script src=""{0}"" async></script>"
```

or passing it where you want the async tag

Use following instead of Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

```
Scripts.RenderFormat(@"<script src=""{0}"" async></script>", "~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: System.Web.Optimization 4.0 seems to have removed both DefaultTagFormat and RenderFormat, disallowing custom script tag output (using AssetManager.RenderScriptTag directly).

Comment: @E-Null The current release now supports both the above methods if you just do `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`

Comment: Where do I need to write those lines ?( one of them..)
And what need upgrade to 1.1 -alpha? the MVC version or the Web Optimization ?
Thanks...

Comment: This breaks CDN fallbacks using `CdnFallbackExpression`. The fallback check will be executed before the deferred script is loading causing the fallback to always kick in.

Comment: I don't see an answer for the question "Where do I need to write those lines?" Specifically, where do we need to place the Scripts.DefaultTagFormat = line?