# Is there any way to get the unminified version of a file using Scripts.Url in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

Looking at the overview here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

It looks like you can use `Scripts.Url` inside a script tag in case you want to decorate the script tag:

```
<script src='@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/modernizr")' async> </script>
```

The problem is regardless of whether the program is running in debug mode, you always get the minified version.

Is there any way to get the same minified/un-minified functionality as `Scripts.Render` with `Scripts.Url`?

**Update**
It looks like you can remove transforms from each bundle to prevent it from actually minifying the bundle. So I added this after declaring each bundle:

```
// If optimizations aren't enabled
if (!BundleTable.EnableOptimizations)
{
    // Iterate over each bundle
    foreach (var b in bundles)
    {
        // And strip out any transformations (minify)
        b.Transforms.Clear();
    }
}
```

Not the prettiest thing, but works for now. If there is an easier way, I'd love to know.

Comment: You should be getting un-minified while running debug mode.

Comment: Sorry to hear that my answer didn't help. Did a bit more digging and came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743703/async-loading-of-javascript-files-using-mvc4-bundling-and-html5-async-attribute.